# Main window doesn't run properly on Snow Leopard

Tags: cocoa, debugging, osx-snow-leopard, orsserialport

My app developed in Xcode 4.5 on Mountain Lion runs flawlessly on Lion and ML.

My Snow Leopard tester reports that when the app starts, it is disabled. By that he means none of the controls are active and the red, yellow, green 'traffic light' is greyed out. If another app is opened that covers my app, when the covering app is moved, any control, or part of a control it covered is not there.

The menu bar is responsive, and my preferences panel works. The app can be shut down from the menu, I don't know if it can be shut from the keyboard.

Another app that uses the same serial code works fine.

I need help with putting together a plan to solve it. I don't know how to trace this.

Comment: Do you not have access to a machine running 10.6 yourself?

Comment: Sadly, no. I thought to install it in Parallels, but can't. The other app  that runs OK is your demo. Nice stuff BTW.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about your app in your question? Is there anything unique or out of the ordinary about your app's user interface? Do you have a console log from the 10.6 tester, and are there any errors or exceptions being logged?

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. On startup, the app reads in saved prefs, if there are any, and opens the serial port. If there is no saved baud and port name, the user must select them from prefs, a notification is passed back to the main app delegate and it again attempts to open the port. AFAIK, there is nothing out of the ordinary, but as new as I am, I probably wouldn't recognize it. ;-o} I could zip the project and email it to you. I don't have the log. I'll request it.

Comment: If you email the project to me, I will take a look at it (and post an answer here if I'm able to figure out what's going on). I have a 10.6 machine handy too.

Comment: Thanks, it's in the aether......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, the problem is that you're expecting data to be in NSUserDefaults. On first launch, NSUserDefaults returns nil for the keys you access, and passing this nil result through later code causes exceptions to be thrown. The solution is to register defaults with NSUserDefaults upon application startup:

```
@implementation AppController
+ (void)initialize
{
    NSDictionary *defaultValues = @{@"SomeKey" : @"DefaultValue"};
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultValues];
}
@end
```